# Is there a reason for preserving icon grid size when changing screen resolution, rather than preserving their on-screen size?

Tags: windows-7, resolution, icons

When you change the screen resolution you change the size that objects appear on the screen. This can cause Windows to shift your desktop icons if the new resolution is lesser than your previous one and they wouldn't be visible in their original arrangement under the new resolution.

What is being employed in Windows operating systems is that the desktop icons and available screen space change size in accordance with the resolution as opposed to icons keeping their size at every resolution in order to always maintain their desktop arrangement.

**My question:** Is there a technical reason that makes it advantageous to change icon display size when changing screen resolution, rather than preserving the same icon display size at all resolutions to ensure your icons are never moved as a consequence of smaller resolutions?

Comment: It would be a major burden for Microsoft designers to explain each design decision. Some are explained on various blogs but they are often just guesses. I suspect this was tried in usability testing but people didn't like it. The loss in icon quality was probably a reason. This is bad enough on a CRT monitor but probably worse on a modern monitor when using a non native resolution.

Comment: @fixer1234, oh, I thought there would be an objective technical reason behind it.

Comment: @fixer1234, I see your point. If you don't mind I will steal that question as my title. :)

Comment: I think you’re confused about resolution “because DPI” vs resolution “because display size”. (Or physical resolution vs logical resolution.) In the latter case, keeping the pixel size is logical because it’s the same with everything else: More content fits on the screen.

Comment: I took a stab at focusing the question more clearly as a strictly technical issue.  Feel free to play with it if it doesn't capture exactly what you were trying to ask.  I think this addresses the opinion-based concern and am going to vote to reopen it.

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks but now I am really confused about your changes and am unsure if they are correct. For example - you mention changing the resolution entails mapping a different amount of content to the same amount of pixels, while it's the other way around when you change a screen resolution from, say 1366x786 to 800x600. Also icons change their size because the amount of pixels changes, keeping the same amount of pixels in the icon grid will not change the icons, since literally nothing has changed. Could you comment?

Comment: On a different monitor of the same physical size but higher resolution, the screen pixels are actually smaller, and vice versa.  If you just set the display resolution to a lower value, the display driver simulates the appearance of larger pixels by using more actual pixels and mapping the content onto them.  If it's mapping onto fewer pixels, the content's original pixels are averaged to combine them.  If it's mapping onto more pixels, the content's original pixels are interpolated to create the additional pixels (cont'd)

Comment: ("the pixels" in the first paragraph refers to whatever pixels are used to render the icon).  So say an icon is created using a 32x32 grid.  On a screen with smaller pixels, the 32x32 will take up less screen space, and vice versa.  If you just set the resolution lower, the system might simulate that by mapping the 32x32 onto say a 40x40 grid of actual pixels.  So the icon will appear larger just as if you had a screen with fewer, larger pixels.  Keep in mind that this is your question, so the wording should be what makes sense to you.

Comment: @fixer1234, in that case I will reword it a bit, thanks for the help though! I'd just like to mention that pixels are always the same size, regardless of resolution. The different resolutions just have different amount of pixels mapped to the same physical constraints, which demonstrates what you said.

Comment: The pixels on a given screen are a fixed size.  But if you have two monitors, both the same physical size, and one has higher resolution than the other, the higher res monitor will have smaller pixels (that's how they fit more in the same space).  Just a thought on your edit--"same size" is a little ambiguous (does it mean same number of icon grid pixels or same visual display size?).  You might want to clarify.  Anyway, good luck.

Comment: @fixer1234, ugh, you are right. I wrote that too early in the morning now I see I'm wrong. :)

Answer (score 2):

Windows has standard [icon sizes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), from the 16x16, 20x20, 32x32, 64x64, 128x128 and 256x256.

Whenever you use an icon, one of this sizes is used. There is a size defined for each case, being it the Explorer Window, the Start Menu, the desktop in normal, small or big size.

It is recommended to use one of the native sizes because they have been rendered to look beautiful at exactly that size. So, if you want an odd icon size, it won't have a perfect look, as expected.

[image: icon sizes]